# How to extends PlayerNotificationManager with Builder to override for compact view controls Exo player 2.14

Tags: android, kotlin, builder, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am looking for a way to extends/inherit PlayerNotificationManager.Builder with new Builder approach in **ExoPlayer version 2.14**. since earlier methods to subclass, it is deprecated now.

**Problem Area** -

```
    private class CustomPlayerNotificationManager(
    context: Context,
    channelId: String,
    notificationId: Int,
    mediaDescriptionAdapter: MediaDescriptionAdapter
) : PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, notificationId, channelId, mediaDescriptionAdapter)
```

Here PlayerNotificationManager.Builder return builder instance so PlayerNotificationManager is not being subclassed and I am unable to override it **getActionIndicesForCompactView** method.

Could anyone help me with subclassing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exo Player version 2.15 has setters for control on compact view. We can set for Seek forward, rewind, etc. In that case we don't need ***getActionIndicesForCompactView()***. But couldn't find a way to subclass PlayerNotificationManager.Builder on 2.14 version